# Replicate some rows in R, keeping some values constant and changing others

Tags: r, row

I have a dataset composed of political parties and their corresponding ideology. Some of these parties have changed their name, but the database does not have these renamed parties. What I want to do is duplicate rows corresponding to political parties which were renamed, keeping their ideological values constant but changing their names accordingly.

For example. Suppose I generate the following data.frame:

`df <- data.frame(party = c("AB", "PQ", "HL", "AS"), ideology = c("left", "center-right", "right", "right"))`

Now suppose that the party AB changed its name to RB. I want to create a new row with a party called RB and its ideology value corresponding to AB's ideology value.

How do I do this in an efficient way? In the real dataset, I have several parties that were renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `data.frame` holding the old and the new name, extract the present information using `match`, overwrite the party name and use `rbind` to join the new data to the present.

```
x <- data.frame(old="AB", new="RB")

y <- df[match(x$old, df$party),]
y$party <- x$new
rbind(df, y)

#  party     ideology
#1    AB         left
#2    PQ center-right
#3    HL        right
#4    AS        right
#5    RB         left
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked as intended

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- tibble(old = "AB", new = "RB")

df %>%
  filter(party == x$old) %>%
  mutate(party = x$new) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

```
  party     ideology
1    AB         left
2    PQ center-right
3    HL        right
4    AS        right
5    RB         left
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rows_upsert`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   rows_upsert(tibble(party = "RB", ideology = df$ideology[df$party == 'AB']))
```

-output

```
 party     ideology
1    AB         left
2    PQ center-right
3    HL        right
4    AS        right
5    RB         left
```